# Are there any custom semantic html tags project for designing html pages?

Tags: html, tags, semantic-markup

I found `Semantic UI` project here: http://semantic-ui.com/

`Semantic` is structured around natural language conventions to make development more intuitive.

For example bellow code creates a menu using `Semantic`:

```
<nav class="ui menu">
  <h3 class="header item">Title</h3>
  <a class="active item">Home</a>
  <a class="item">Link</a>
  <a class="item">Link</a>
  <span class="right floated text item">
    Signed in as <a href="#">user</a>
  </span>
</nav>
```

instead of `Bootstrap` CSS classes:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <p class="navbar-text pull-right">Signed in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">User</a></p>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

My question is: Are there any custom semantic html tags project for designing html pages?

Something like this:

```
<menu>
    <menu-header>Title</menu-header>
    <menu-item active="true">Home</menu-item>
    <menu-item>Link</menu-item>
    <menu-item>Link</menu-item>
</menu>
```

Comment: In order for it to use your custom tags, you'd have to heavily modify the XML or whatever background structure is in place. This would seem to completely negate any benefit of such a project, unless it was widely used by your clients.

Answer (score 0):

There are some of them in the HTML5 definition, for instance the `<article>` one from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Content_sectioning.

`<menu>` happens to be an other one of them : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/menu.